# descryption of string from Encrypted-AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: encryption

If I am given a representation of `Encrypted-AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding(s1, s2, s3)` where `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are some random strings, how can I know what the decrypted string looks like?

Comment: Do you have the AES key?

Comment: since I am not exactly sure, what does `s1`, `s2`, `s3` mean here, aren't the the keys/salt?

Comment: You will have to explain what your notation means.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the encryption keys and the initialization vector/salt, you can't.  Otherwise there wouldn't be much point encrypting it :)

Comment: The IV might possibly be prepended to the cyphertext.  Decryption without the key is effectively impossibly unless you are a government agency with a lot of money/time.